# Necessity to unregister Broadcast Receiver which is not declared in manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

Is it necessary to unregister "Broadcast Receiver" when its not mentioned in the manifest file of my Android Studio Project? What are the consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext())

> If used from an Activity context, the receiver is being registered
>   within that activity. This means that you are expected to unregister
>   before the activity is done being destroyed; in fact if you do not do
>   so, the framework will clean up your leaked registration as it removes
>   the activity and log an error. Thus, if you use the Activity context
>   to register a receiver that is static (global to the process, not
>   associated with an Activity instance) then that registration will be
>   removed on you at whatever point the activity you used is destroyed.

Thus, you needn't to unregister your BroadcaseReceiver if you associate it with an `Activity`.

Comment: but, I think it's better practice to unregister it programatically before activity is destroyed, though the BroadcastReciever is unregistered upon the destruction of context activity as per your explaination :)

Comment: yes, it's generally better to do that. We just don't HAVE TO

Answer (score 0):

If your `BroadcastReceiver` is started in the `onCreate()` method it has to be unregistered so that when your activity is started again it doesn't make another one thus resulting in multiple `BroadcastReceivers`.

Comment: but, if I register it in 'onCreate()' then I think only restarting the app will be able to call the 'onCreate()' function again ..... so in that case there won't be multiple 'BroadcastReceivers' cause the previous one will automatically be unregistered by then upon destruction of activity....... and if activity is not destroyed, returning to the activity will call 'onRestart()'->'onStart()'->'onResume()' not 'onCreate()'.........
Is there anything wrong in my understanding?

Comment: No the previous one won't be destroyed on `onDestroy()` unless you mention it on the code.

Comment: The activity tries to clean up but often what happens is it produces errors. It could happen. For best results unregister it.